# Magento index.php with Geoip

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, geoip

I wrote a little piece of code for Magento in index.php to automatically switch store-view based on the country_code from Geoip.

The code works fine, but I'm not an expert and I'm not able to judge if I wrote the code effectively recourse-wise.

I think it would better to save the countryCode to the session. I know how to do this in extensions, but I can't figure out how to do this in index.php.

```
$geocountryCode = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$countryList = array("AT","BE","BG","CY","CZ","DK","EE","FI","FR","DE","GR","HU","IE","IT","LV","LT","LU","MT","NL","PL","PT","SK","SI","ES","SE","GB","RO");

    if(!in_array($geocountryCode, $countryList)) {
        $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'int';
        $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

    } else {
        $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'default';
        $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
    }

    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Best regards,

Remy

Comment: Just tried this in M2 and doesn't work getting error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage'" - Have you updated for M2?